# why listbox1.Items.Add use Equals Method of my Object?

Tags: c#, .net, listbox, equals

i'm scrutinizing Windows Forms ListBoxCollection Add Method,
during the analyzing i found that the method "add" calls Equals method in base Object
why this method do this action ?

---

I Have used "Call Stack"  and I have Find This Answer :

We Call :System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection.Add(object item)

and it will Call : System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection.AddInternal(object item)

and it will Call : System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.NativeAdd(object item)

and it will call : System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.GetItemText(object item)

and it will call : System.Windows.Forms.Formatter.FormatObject(object value, System.Type targetType, System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter sourceConverter, System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter targetConverter, string formatString, System.IFormatProvider formatInfo, object formattedNullValue, object dataSourceNullValue)

and it will call :System.Windows.Forms.Formatter.IsNullData(object value, object dataSourceNullValue)

and Finally it will call : object.Equals(object objA, object objB)

which This Method Make My Equal Method too Run :

WindowsFormsApplication1.Student.Equals(object obj)

and The Last Parameter which Will be Send to My Equals Method (as obj)   is a DBNULL Object !
what is a DBNULL  ?

Comment: Hard to guess, Winforms doesn't have a ListBoxCollection class.  ListBox.ObjectCollection.Add() would be next likely candidate but its Add() method doesn't call Equals() unless the list is sorted.  Look at the call stack to see how it got there.

Answer (score 2):

Because it needs to be able to know what item is firing events. If the objects are the exact same object, selection, editing, deletion becomes difficult and confusing.

Comment: sorry but would it be Possible for you to Explain More ?I don't Understand :-S

Comment: I have to make a lot of assumption since you didn't provide a lot of information. But if the objects equal each other, and are the same. When you remove that object from the list which item are you removing? Both, just one? Since they are the same it's a confusing operation.

Comment: alright !in Remove(object obj) Method it's Reasonable but in Add(object obj) Method i don't Understand Reason yet !

Comment: well, you can't call Remove without having first called Add. So it's like a chicken or the egg kind of problem