# NullReference Exception when adding object to a ListBox in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm trying to add an object of the type Customer I created to a ListBox in Windows Forms, but the Equals method of my Customer class throws a NullReferenceException.

Here's (a stripped down version of) my Customer Class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Customer( string firstName, string lastName )
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.LastName;
    }

    public override bool Equals( object obj )
    {
        Customer p = obj as Customer;
        return this.FirstName.Equals( p.FirstName ) && this.LastName.Equals( p.LastName );
    }
}
```

And here is how I try to add a Customer object to the ListBox:

```
private void addCustomerButton_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(new Customer( customerFirstNameTextBox.Text, customerLastNameTextBox.Text ));
    }
```

When adding a new item to the ListBox, it triggers 'Equals' for the items, as explained here: [why listbox1.Items.Add use Equals Method of my Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703435/why-listbox1-items-add-use-equals-method-of-my-object).

I can solve this problem easily by catching the NullReferenceException in the Equals method of my Customer class, but here's what I don't get:

Why does ListBox call `Equals` method with an null object as a parameter?

Comment: The Equals method should work correctly with any argument. And it's not about catching an exception. You must add a checking of the type of the input value, and handle the situation when FirstName or LastName is null (or just use Equals (a, b)).

Comment: You are not using `Equals` correct. At first you want to take `obj` as `Customer`, but then you send `Equals` **p.FirstName** which is `string`.

Comment: This is not really a duplicate, at least part of it. You can refer to the linked question to understand the first part of your question. The second is, you need to change your casting logic, as the list box might contain many objects, your casting should expect null values, thus you should return false directly if the object is not of the same class: `Customer p = obj as Customer; if (p == null) return false;`.